# What is my VE status?

Tags: united-states, license, arrl, volunteer-examiners

I was an ARRL VE years ago. The info about ARRL VEs says that you remain a VE and the only way one will be dropped is loss of license. However, years ago to be a valid VE one would have to have a current date sticker on one's badge. Am I still a VE? Do I need the date sticker?

Answer (score 6):

For general info, check http://www.arrl.org/volunteer-examiners.  It will point you to a PDF manual for ARRL VEC.

From http://www.arrl.org/files/file/VEs/VE%20Manual%20Web%20FINAL%202014.pdf:

> "Once accredited as an examiner in the ARRL/VEC’s program, your
>   accreditation credentials will be good until your FCC license
>   expires."

Also

> "ARRL accreditation renewal is automatic for ARRL VEs who maintain a
>   current address, contact phone number and/or email address on file at
>   the VEC office **and have participated at an exam session within the
>   past 5 years**. *(Emphasis added.)* Renewal stickers, extending the ARRL VE’s accreditation
>   expiration date, are issued and should be placed on your credentials.
>   By issuing automatic accreditation renewals, the ARRL/VEC can ensure
>   that the needs of our VEs are met; as well as the amateur radio
>   community. After 5 years of inactivity, your VE accreditation will be
>   placed on hold until you contact the VEC office. Depending on the
>   amount of time that has passed, you may be required to reapply. No
>   one's accreditation will be permanently revoked solely because of his
>   or her inactivity, because many factors can contribute to a VE’s
>   activity level."

If you want to reactivate your credential, contact the VEC office vec@arrl.org or call (860) 594-0300.

Comment: The folks in the VEC office are very helpful by email. I helped do two 75+ person exams (university extra credit was offered for an undergrad core engineering course) on the email from the VEC saying I was accredited. It also helped that I was licensed by that same team.